# How to do dynamic scaling using pg_shard

Tags: dynamic, scaling

I am doing data base scaling using postgresql.
Currently i am using [pg_shard](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_shard) for scaling and  able to do sharding and replication. i have tested the example that mentioned in Readme file of pg_shard.
But i need  dynamically scale a cluster as new machines are added or old ones are retired.I am using google cloud VM to setup database .So once one VM is filled with data i want to setup new instance with same configuration.
ie,if the current machine size is 4GB and is of out of memory then it should create one more VM with 4GB size and next entries should come there.
I have gone through http://slideplayer.com/slide/4896815/ and after reading this i understood that it is possible to do but the steps are not mentioned anywhere.
How to achieve this using pg_shard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer myself.
We can use CitusDB for this.
CitusDB is installed with an extension called "shard_rebalancer", which helps you to move the shards around when new nodes are added to the cluster. For this, you need to follow the installation instructions for CitusDB.

In this documentation, you can find about the related information for the shard rebalancer functions (i.e., rebalance_table_shards and replicate_table_shards)

With simpler words, you must follow the steps:
Add CitusDB node(s) to the cluster 
Add the IPs (or host names) to pg_worker_list.conf
Reload the master node configuration, so that the master becomes aware of the new worker node(s)
Run `"SELECT rebalance_table_shards('tablename')"` on the master node.

Comment: Should be worth mentioning that `rebalance_table_shards` and a couple other functions are not available on the free Community Edition.